# How to combine two input patterns in HTML?

Tags: html, regex

I need to combine two input patterns into one.

1. First symbol contains 1: `^[1]\d*$`
2. Min, max length contains 8: `.{8}`

What expression should I use?

Comment: Try this `[1]\d{7}$`

Comment: Thank you, @AbhishekPandey, it works :) Why did they downvote my question, what's wrong?

Comment: I guess someone has found something wrong with your question and forgot to comment after downvote

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat `{7}` digits instead of repeating the digits with `*`, to ensure the string has 8 digits total:

```
^1\d{7}$
```